# How to provide a GFF/GTF file to Chromonomer

Tags: gff3, gtf

I am trying to use [Chromonomer](http://catchenlab.life.illinois.edu/chromonomer/). It should be possible (according to the software page and a paper) to add a GFF/GTF file to the analysis.

Alas, neither the built-in help nor some light source code browsing were enough to find a way of passing the file to the software.

How can I use a GFF or a GTF file with Chromonomer?

Answer (score 1):

I think the part of the code that should allow you to do this is in `chromomer.cc`.

Lines 2857-2983 form the function `parse_command_line`. Nowhere is there any reference to anything resembling parsing a GFF file, so I think the documentation is not in line with the code at this point.

For reference, I looked at version 1.07. It would be helpful if the code were on github.

Comment: The distribution of Chromonomer comes with a script for translation.